# How to trigger TC builds on specific commit comments only

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I'm using TC 9.0 with Git. I would like to setup VCS Triggers for all pull requests merges only. I've tried with VCS Trigger Rules:

```
-:**
+:comment=^Merge pull request:**
```

but with no luck so far (it didn't caught any change no matter of commit message).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set internal property `teamcity.vcsTrigger.analyzeFullHistoryForMergeCommits=false`. For more details see the [comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24747#comment=27-814689) in TeamCity issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Try

+:refs/pull/*/merge

You can find more information over [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/automatically-building-pull-requests-from-github-with-teamcity/)

Comment: But this assumes that all merges are made on 'pull/...' branches which is not true in my case